# I can't show images in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I can't show images in Flutter.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
title: "hahahahahaha",
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawer: Drawer(
        child: Container(
      child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset("assets\images\info.jpg"),
            onTap: () {
              print("Pressed!");
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
    )),
    body: Center(child: Text("Haha"))),
));
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: fluttermytry
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
   assets:
     - assets/images/info.jpg
```

I am trying to add images on Drawer with using ListTile but i can't. I'm trying to do this for last 5 hours. I clicked nearly every link about my problem. Please help me.

Edit: I forgot the writing error:

```
 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
 C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart- 
 sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  
 throw_
 packages/flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart 227:55                                                                     
 load
 C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart- 
 sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            
<fn>
   C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart- 
   sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1362:47                                          
   _rootRunUnary
   C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart- 
   sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1265:19                                          
   runUnary
 ...
 Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assetsimagesinfo.jpg")
 Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#6a00f(), 
 name: "assetsimagesinfo.jpg", scale: 1)
```

Random for limit: lsdhflkjashflkjashfkjashdjfklhasjkfhaPOIRJKASHFJKSAHFJKASGHFDKJLHSAKLJHFKASHFASJFHLKJSAHFJASHFLKJASHFKJASHFKJASHFLKASHLFKJHASLKFJHASLKJFHASKJLFHLKASJHF

Comment: Check the path where you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have placed your asset in the pubsec using `assets/images/info.jpg`.

But while using it, you are using it with `assets\images\info.jpg`.

The `\` should be replaced with `/`.
Could this be the source of the issue ?

If you check the error it mentions `assetsimagesinfo.jpg` and not `assets/images/info.jpg`.
This is because `assets\images\info.jpg` === `assetsimagesinfo.jpg`.

With the forward slash, you are just escaping the character `i` when you write `\images` or `\info` which converts them to `images` and `info`.

The below code works perfectly.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  drawer: Drawer(
      child: Container(
    child: ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      children: [
        ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset("assets/images/info.jpg"),
          onTap: () {
            print("Pressed!");
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
  )),
  body: Center(child: Image.asset('assets/images/info.jpg')));
}
```

Folder structure

- lib

  - main.dart
- assets

  - images

    - info.jpg

[image]

Comment: Nope. it does not work. And i forgot to add error the complier gave.

Comment: Have updated the answer to include working code and the folder structure. If that code doesn't work, check if your folder structure is right.

Comment: Glad to have helped.